# How to resize second monitor display area

Tags: display

I am very new to Linux in general and elementary in particular (2-3 days) so this question might be dumb. I do the majority of my work on a second HDMI monitor. In windows, i could resize the display area to 76% so that nothing was hidden behind the edges of the monitor, but i can't seem to understand how to do this in elementary. I've tried xrandr's scale command but it only changes the resolution without allowing me to view the full picture.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it is quite inconvenient. Also, please explain everything as if you were talking to an imbecile because i'm not yet completely comfortable with even the most basic commands.

Thanks

Comment: Okay, welcome to the elementary OS community, I hope you will have a great time using elementary OS. Now, could you explain what do you mean exactly by resizing to 76%? Do you reduce the screen real estate on which the image is shown (the rest is black), or did you mean changing the resolution? Are you using a mirroring setup (same image on two monitors) or "extended" setup (where each monitor shows a different image)?

Comment: I think he is talking about reducing the screen real estate, I am in the exact same boat given the very limited resolution options and the MBA it requires to add resolutions only to have it not effect the edges.
Something like a litte under and over scanning.
I too am using a HDMI seeing that this is all thats available to me and I can see .8th of an inch of the top Panel bar, so I don't even know whats up there
and on the bottom I have to blow the icons in that toolbar up to "87" to be able to not have them cut off by the edge of the screen.No full screen anything for me either seeing this ef

Comment: ::EDIT:: @Aleksandar Stefanović

Comment: ::EDIT:: @Aleksandar Stefanović    You can fix this but like with most it is kind of dangerous. I fixed mine by following these steps in adding the nVidia drivers for Ubuntu 16.6, the overscan tool is in the nVidia manager in Elementary and allows for reshaping the desktop. Here is the link : https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa Pay attention and follow the instructions and you will be fine, there is no threat of black screen doing it this way as well. Good Luck